# ASP.NET Web API returns empty collection in json response

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities

OK, I have a problem with the ASP.NET Web API. I followed [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-1) tutorial on how to create it. I mdified the tutorial for my purposes.

I have a patch class which has a Collection of download URLs. The API is returning every information just fine, only the collection of DownloadURLs is returned as null. 
However when I stepped through the code step by step debugging it, it returned the collection properly.
What did I do wrong. I'm not able to find my error.
Here is the Model:

```
public class Patch
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("PatchVersion")]
    public string PatchVersion { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("Length")]
    public long Length { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("VersionToUpdateFrom")]
    public string VersionToUpdateFrom { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("DownloadUris")]
    public ICollection<DownloadUri> DownloadUris { get; set; }
}

public class DownloadUri
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("AbsolutePath")]
    public string AbsolutePath { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [JsonProperty("IndirectDownload")]
    public bool IndirectDownload { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DataContext class:

```
public class PatchesContext : DbContext
{
    public PatchesContext()
        : base("name=PatchesContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Patch> Patches { get; set; }

    public DbSet<DownloadUri> DownloadUris { get; set; }
}
```

This is the ContextInitializer

```
public class PatchesContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<PatchesContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(PatchesContext context)
    {

        var downloadUri = new List<DownloadUri>
        {
            new DownloadUri
            {
                AbsolutePath = "http://downloadUri1.test", IndirectDownload = false
            },
            new DownloadUri
            {
                AbsolutePath = "http://downloadUri2.test", IndirectDownload = false
            }
        };

        var patches = new List<Patch>
        {
            new Patch
            {
                Length = 100000, PatchVersion = "1.0.0.0", VersionToUpdateFrom = string.Empty, DownloadUris = downloadUri
            },
            new Patch
            {
                DownloadUris = null, Length = 10000, PatchVersion = "1.1.0.0", VersionToUpdateFrom = "1.0.0.0"
            }
        };
        patches.ForEach(p => context.Patches.Add(p));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And finally here is my controller class. I left out the Post, Put and Delete Methods, because I didn't test them yet (no point if get is not working):

```
public class AdminController : ApiController
{
    private PatchesContext db = new PatchesContext();

    // GET api/Admin
    public IEnumerable<Patch> GetPatches()
    {
        return db.Patches.AsEnumerable();
    }

    // GET api/Admin/5
    public Patch GetPatch(string version)
    {
        Patch patch = db.Patches.Find(version);
        if (patch == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return patch;
    }
}
```

I hope you all can help me and thanks.

/edit: 
The Header looks like this:

```
Status Code: 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 291
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 25 Oct 2013 17:25:48 GMT
Expires: -1
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RTpcVXNlcnNcUm9iZXJ0XERvY3VtZW50c1xWaXN1YWwgU3R1ZGlvIDIwMTJcUHJvamVjdHNcTjQ0V2Vic2l0ZVxONDRXZWJzaXRlXGFwaVxhZG 1pbg==?=
```

The Response Body looks like this:

```
[

  {
    "$id": "1",
    "PatchVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "Length": 100000,
    "VersionToUpdateFrom": "",
    "DownloadUris": null
  },
  {
    "$id": "2",
    "PatchVersion": "1.1.0.0",
    "Length": 10000,
    "VersionToUpdateFrom": "1.0.0.0",
    "DownloadUris": null
  }
]
```

Comment: So you're getting a 200 success code but no data? When you put a breakpoint on your Web API action, are you returning something that's not null?

Comment: can we see example of json?

Comment: I added the response header and body to my initial post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not explicitly loading the Patch.DownloadUris property nor is that property virtual so its not going to lazy load it either.

Either explicitly load it via an Include for DownloadUris on this line:

```
Patch patch = db.Patches.Find(version);
```

to (untested)

```
Patch patch = db.Patches.Find(version).Include("DownloadUris");
```

Or make that property virtual and ensure lazy loading is enabled on your context.

Edit note:
given in your code sample for the Seed method, only Patch (1.0.0.0) will have values for DownloadUris, since in Patch (1.1.0.0) you are setting that property to null

Comment: So if I understand it right, I have to make the properties on the DownloadUri class virtual? Will try that.

Comment: No, make the DownloadUris property in the Patch class virtual

Comment: added explicit loading example, not tested as i'm away from my IDE.

Comment: Yep, making the collection property virtual did it. So I'm going to accept this as my answer. Anything I should know by making it virtual. I know this has something to do with inheritance, but I had never too much to do with it. Is ther anything I should watch out for?

Comment: yes you should watch out something! ;) (i'll come back to this and post a followup comment if someone else doesn't quicker) you should really get up on explicit and implicit loading. It's a little tricker than many first think, but very cool when you get used to how to use it.

Comment: Would be great if you could point me into the direction of some tutorials/articles on loading.

Comment: Well thank you for that. Will definitely read it. Now I just need a way to connect this whole thing to a MSSQL database. and I'll be good to go.